# How to configure Anaconda to use Tensorflow on Windows now that OS is officially supported

Tags: pip, tensorflow, anaconda, spyder, conda

Finally has been released Tensorflow for Windows. I have installed latest version of tensorflow on windows from official repo with

```
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

But is unclear how to configure it to work with Anaconda environment, since part of the official online documentation is outdated and doesn't show the right syntax to link my Tensorflow installation to Anaconda environment on Windows so that I can use Tensorflow with Spyder in this OS without any Virtual Machine.

Comment: You need to use the pip from you Anaconda environment. Which pip are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow is available for Windows but at this time hasn't been uploaded to `conda` package manager, however you can install it using `pip`. If you have a default Python installation and Anaconda use its own Python distribution you have to use integrated Python distribution in Anaconda launching **Anaconda Prompt**

If installer haven't created the Anaconda Prompt link, the command is

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe "/K" "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat" "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3"
```

(obviously adjust path if you have installed Anaconda in a different directory).

In the Anaconda Prompt launch:

-> For CPU version

```
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

-> For GPU version

```
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-0.12.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

Done this you should be able to use Tensorflow in Anaconda environment, otherwise Tensorflow will be installed in your default Python environment and is not visible in Anaconda that by default uses a separated Python setup.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

then, if you want the GPU version,

```
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-0.12.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: already done this, as I have said the problem is "how to configure Anaconda to see Tensorflow installation"

Comment: Did you try to launch the first mnist example from prompt? This works for me.

Comment: I have tried to use some tensorflow script with spyder and doesn't find tensorflow. Do you have installed Anaconda as your unique Python environment without any other Python installation?

Comment: Yes, Anaconda is my unique Python environment. Try to use Anaconda prompt to understand if the problem is spyder or the installation itself.